# How do typescript amd modules work and why do I keep getting errors

Tags: typescript, requirejs, amd

A previous one was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39340696/1641941). Current one is `Overview/reachbz.ts(3,28): error TS2306: File 'typings/immutable-3.8.1.d.ts' is not a module.`

Can anyone explain to me how amd modules work in typescript? After reading the information on the typescript page I still can't figure out how it works and what goes wrong.

I have a git repo to reproduce the error:

```
 git clone https://github.com/amsterdamharu/typescriptHorrors.git
```

`
As requested; here are the files:

```
///<reference path="../typings/immutable-3.8.1.d.ts" />
import Immutable = require("typings/immutable-3.8.1");//error here
console.log("Immutable:",Immutable);
```

/typings/immutable-3.8.1.d.ts here: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/Immutable.d.ts

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "watch": false,
        "module": "amd",
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": ".",
        "rootDir": "."
    }
}
```

task.json (for vscode)

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc.cmd",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

This runs on a windows machine but tried at home on linux with the same error. Using tsc node:

```
[me@localhost ts]$ tsc
Overview/reachbz.ts(4,28): error TS2306: File 'typings/immutable-3.8.1.d.ts' is not a module.
```

Code compiles and works with requirejs but the errors prevent me from publishing this.

That is another thing I don't really understand. Typescript was supposed to be optionally intrusive yet it escalates things that should be warnings (produces valid script after compiling) to errors so in Visual Studio you cannot publish the project.

**[UPDATE]**

Changing the content of the definition file with:

```
export var whatever
```

Makes the error go away.

But the following content will cause the error to come back

```
declare module Immutable {}

declare module "immutable" {
  export = Immutable
}
```

Is there anyone who can compile the git repo? It uses the original immutable git repo definition file but I can't get it to work with node tsc Version 1.8.10

Comment: Please include relevant code and information in this question even if it can be found in the other thread you linked to.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Added some more content as requested. I wonder if anyone can compile this without an error. There seem to be something wrong with the type definition.

Answer (score 2):

In your code :

```
import Immutable = require("typings/immutable-3.8.1");//error here
```

Is an *absolute no no*.

First: You don't need to download any type definitions for `immutable`. They come with immutable js.

Secondarily: You don't `require` TypeScript *definitions*. You actually require *the actually runtime thing*. In your case it would be `immutable` so `import Immutable = require('immutable')`.

## More

Ambient definitions are designed to match *javascript runtime imports*. So you get the typescript definitions into your compilation context (e.g. by using tsconfig.json) and then just write JavaScript. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess based on the content of the definition file typescript uses different rules to resolve the string you pass to require. In this case because the definition has:

```
declare module "immutable" {
  export = Immutable;
}
```

I need to require with the string "immutable" and the [name of the definition file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39326821/typescript-cannot-find-module/39340696#39340696) does not matter.

Changing the definition file to:

```
declare module "reverseEngineerInsteadOfDocumented" {
  export = Immutable;
}
```

Works when you change the string passed to require to:

```
import Immutable = require("reverseEngineerInsteadOfDocumented");
```